# How to create custom buttons in custom tableCell in each cell i need three images

Tags: ios

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

HomeVCTableViewCell *cell = (HomeVCTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[HomeVCTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

int imageNumber = 0;

for (int i = (indexPath.row * imagesCount); i < ((indexPath.row *imagesCount) + imagesCount); i++) {

        if (i < [cellImageVOArray count]) { // If resultsArray Count is odd then we no need to create cell image

            PhotoVO *photoVo = (PhotoVO *)[cellImageVOArray objectAtIndex:i];

            cell.photobutton.frame=CGRectMake(((imageNumber * 5)+5)+(imageNumber * width), 2, width, height -4);

            cell.photobutton.tag = i + 100;
            [[cell.photobutton layer] setBorderWidth:3.0f];
            [[cell.photobutton layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];

            [cell.photobutton addTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            [cell.photobutton setBackgroundImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:photoVo.thumb_URL1] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loader.png"]];
            imageNumber ++;



        }

    }



return cell;
```

}

CustomCell.m

```
   - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self)
    {
        // Initialization code

        NSLog(@"Content View = %f",self.contentView.frame.size.height);
        photobutton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [self.contentView addSubview:photobutton];



    }
    return self;
}
```

In the above code i got only lastbutton of the cell in every cell it was repeating please tell how to display three buttons in each cell Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self)
    {
        btn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        btn1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 35); // set as u required.
        [self.contentView addSubview:btn1];

        btn2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        btn2.frame = CGRectMake(65, 0, 50, 35); // set as u required.
        [self.contentView addSubview:btn2];

        btn3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        btn3.frame = CGRectMake(120, 0, 50, 25); // set as u required.
        [self.contentView addSubview:btn3];

    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: I want display buttons in table view depending on my images array count.suppose my images array count is 20.i want these images each row  has 3 like that 6 rows and last cell contain 2 images

Comment: @user2160953 edit your answer because its not clear what exactly you want.