# Customize the buttons in UITableView Cell

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios7

I have the functionality for "Swipe to delete" the TableViewCell. I want to add one more button with delete. Please see the image

I am using this UITableView Delegate Function to delete the tableview cell.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:
  (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

[image]

Is this possible, and how to access the Extra button?

Thanks.

Comment: You can make a custom cell with button. On touchupinside pass the index path and remove particular data from data source and reload the table

Comment: I think there is no possibility of adding the one more button.Try to make make custom swiping so you can add more buttons as per your requirement.

Comment: You might wanna have a look at this http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/reproducing-the-ios-7-mail-apps-interface/

Comment: Please go through below link it's same as your requirement.
http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/swtableviewcell-expose-utility-buttons-with-an-easy-to-use-uitableviewcell-subclass/

Comment: Possible duplicate of 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721364/add-buttons-programatically-to-table-view-cells
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15362526/how-to-create-custom-buttons-in-custom-tablecell-in-each-cell-i-need-three-image

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link and download sample app : https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/SideSwipeTableView

And customize your uitableviewcell with multiple button.

```
 UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds))];
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds) + kCatchWidth, CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds));
scrollView.delegate = self;
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;

[self.contentView addSubview:scrollView];
self.scrollView = scrollView;

UIView *scrollViewButtonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds) - kCatchWidth, 0, kCatchWidth, CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds))];
self.scrollViewButtonView = scrollViewButtonView;
[self.scrollView addSubview:scrollViewButtonView];

// Set up our two buttons
UIButton *moreButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
moreButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.78f green:0.78f blue:0.8f alpha:1.0f];
moreButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, kCatchWidth / 3.0f, CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds));
[moreButton setTitle:@"More" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[moreButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[moreButton addTarget:self action:@selector(userPressedMoreButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.scrollViewButtonView addSubview:moreButton];

UIButton *shareButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
shareButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1.0f];
shareButton.frame = CGRectMake(kCatchWidth / 3.0f, 0, kCatchWidth / 3.0f, CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds));
[shareButton setTitle:@"Share" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[shareButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[shareButton addTarget:self action:@selector(userPressedMoreButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.scrollViewButtonView addSubview:shareButton];

UIButton *deleteButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
deleteButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:0.231f blue:0.188f alpha:1.0f];
deleteButton.frame = CGRectMake(kCatchWidth / 3.0f+kCatchWidth / 3.0f, 0, kCatchWidth / 3.0f, CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds));
[deleteButton setTitle:@"Delete" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[deleteButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(userPressedDeleteButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.scrollViewButtonView addSubview:deleteButton];

UIView *scrollViewContentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds))];
scrollViewContentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.scrollView addSubview:scrollViewContentView];
self.scrollViewContentView = scrollViewContentView;

UILabel *scrollViewLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(self.scrollViewContentView.bounds, 10, 0)];
self.scrollViewLabel = scrollViewLabel;
[self.scrollViewContentView addSubview:scrollViewLabel];
```

- I have implemented this code with my app got such result. You can and number of button in cell swipe.

  Here is implemented screen shots

  [image]After swipe the cell 3 buttons appears "More","Share","Delete".

Comment: Its ok Buddy i can already did this functionality, anyway Thanks for Help